# Function mismatch between vectors with identical stored types

Tags: c++, vector, allocator, function-templates

I have define a template function called `"Create2DBBox"` just for create bounding boxes from a point cloud vector, the implementation details are less important.

I want to use the template `PointT` type for accepting different Point type such as `PointXYZ` or `PointXYZI', the problem is when I define the function like below:
```

```
template<typename PointT>
std::vector<BBox2D> Create2DBBox(const std::shared_ptr<std::vector<pcl::PointCloud<PointT>, Eigen::aligned_allocator<pcl::PointCloud<PointT> >>> cloudVecIn, const Eigen::MatrixXf& projectMatrix, const cv::Size& imageSize)
{
  std::vector<BBox2D> bbox_vec_res;
  for(int i = 0; i < cloudVecIn->size(); ++i) {
    BBox2D bbox((*cloudVecIn)[i], projectMatrix, imageSize);
    bbox_vec_res.push_back(bbox);
  }
  return bbox_vec_res;
}
```

When I use this function as below:

```
 std::shared_ptr<std::vector<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>>> clustered_vec = ogm_detector_.get_clustered_cloud_vec();
 vector<BBox2D> bbox_vec = sensors_fusion::Create2DBBox(clustered_vec, this->transform_matrix_, Size(this->image_raw_.cols, image_raw_.rows));
```

I get the error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘Create2DBBox(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI> > >&, Eigen::MatrixXf&, cv::Size)’
 D> bbox_vec = sensors_fusion::Create2DBBox(clustered_vec, this->transform_matrix_, Size(this->image_raw_.cols, image_raw_.rows));
```

I don't know, and I guess it must be the fisrt template argument cause. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

They are not the same, as your function tales a shared pointer to a vector with a custom allocator.

As your function doesn't depend on the allocator, do:

```
template<typename Container>
std::vector<BBox2D> Create2DBBox(const std::shared_ptr<Container> cloudVecIn, const Eigen::MatrixXf& projectMatrix, const cv::Size& imageSize)
```

And even, you don't need the shared pointer, so:

```
template<typename Container>
std::vector<BBox2D> Create2DBBox(const Container& cloudVecIn, const Eigen::MatrixXf& projectMatrix, const cv::Size& imageSize)
```